# Use startActivityForResult from non-activity

Tags: java, android

I have MainActivity  which is an Activity and other class(which is a simple java class), we'll call it "SimpleClass".

Now I want to run from that class the command `startActivityForResult`.

I though that I could pass that class (SimpleClass), using only MainActivity's context, but the problem is that we can't run `context.startActivityForResult(...);`.

So, the only way making SimpleClass to use `startActivityForResult`, is to pass the reference of MainActivity as an Activity variable to the SimpleClass.

Something like that:

Inside the MainActivity class I created the instance of SimpleClass like this way:

```
SimpleClass simpleClass = new SimpleClass(MainActivity.this);
```

---

Now, this is how SimpleClass looks like:

```
public Class SimpleClass {

Activity myMainActivity;

   public SimpleClass(Activity mainActivity) {
       super();
       this.myMainActivity=mainActivity;    
   }
....


    public void someMethod(...) {
        myMainActivity.startActivityForResult(...);
    }

}
```

Now it's working, but isn't there a proper way of doing this? I am afraid I could have some memory leaks in the future.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do but you should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253088/passing-activity-to-non-activity-object-properly).

Comment: By doing this could you use the `onActivityResult` method inside your simpleClass or you did not intend to? [Same problem here..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557087/how-to-get-the-result-from-onactivityresult-inside-another-classoutside-of-the/25557182?noredirect=1#comment39915501_25557182)

Answer (score 69):

I don't know if this is good practice or not, but `casting a Context object to an Activity object` compiles fine.

Try this:

```
if (mContext instanceof Activity) {
        ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(...);
} else {
        Log.e("mContext should be an instanceof Activity.");
}
```

This should compile, and the results should be delivered to the actual activity holding the context.

Comment: How about if context is passed from a service ?

Comment: No, it does launch a cast exception!

Comment: A Context is not inevitably an Activity (for example if it's get with `myActivity.getApplicationContext()`

Comment: If the goal is to avoid a memory leak, what advantage is there to holding a context as a member variable of a class over holding an activity? Doesn't storing a context have the same potential to lead to a memory leak as storing an activity?

Answer (score 4):

If you need to get the result from the previous Activity, then your calling class needs to be of type Activity.

What is the purpose of you calling `Activity.startActivityForResult()` if you never use the result (at least according to the sample code you posted).

Does `myMainActivity` do anything with the result? If so, then just make `SimpleClass` a subclass of Activity and handle the result from within `SimpleClass` itself.
If `myMainActivity` needs the result, then maybe you should refactor the code to start the activity from `myMainActivity`.

Comment: I am using result, just i wanna seperate it to diffrent class, so i was wondering how should i pass an Activity parameter to a non-activity class, without causing leaks in the future.

Comment: What about making SimpleClass a nested class?

Answer (score 1):

Better solution is :

1. Making `SimpleClass` a subclass of your `Activity` class
2. calling another Activity as `startActivityForResult`
3. handling the result within `SimpleClass` itself

Comment: sounds like this should work, but I got this: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference`