# Context from Activity vs Service

Tags: java, android

I have a Preference wrapper class which I am using like this:

```
public final class Preferences implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener 
{
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    Context context;
    private final int FB_REQUESTCODE=1;
    private final int FB_SELCTFRIENDS=2;


    public Preferences(Context context)
    {
        this.context=context;
        this.sharedPreferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }


    public String getFBFriends()
    {

        return sharedPreferences.getString(Keys.FB_FRIENDS.key, Defaults.FB_FRIENDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
            String key)
    {

        if (key.equals(Keys.FB_FRIENDS.key))
        {
            String fbFriendsVal = getFBFriends();
            if (fbFriendsVal.equals(Consts.FB_FRIENDS_FIRE))
            {
                if(context instanceof Activity)
                {
                Activity activity = (Activity) context;
                activity.startActivityForResult(new Intent(context,
                        FriendPickerActivity.class), FB_SELCTFRIENDS);
                }
                else if (context instanceof Service)
                {
                    Service service=(Service) context;
                    service.startActivity(new Intent(context,
                        FriendPickerActivity.class), null);

                }
                else
                {
                    Log.e(App.TAG, "Could not start FB Friends Activity");
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Here FB_FRIENDS refer to a key of `ListPreference`. Upon user selecting a particular item in this list, I want to fire an activity for result, which I am doing in `onSharedPreferenceShared` method.

The problem is the `context`. I am using this preference class from various places within my application such as `Activty` and `Service`. Since inside the service, I do not maintain activity context, I simply pass the Service context.

Now the problem is since, `startActivityForResult` is obviously not applicable for service class and that's when I get `ClassCastException` (If I do not put that logic of checking instance class).

I have thought few solutions about it:

1. Maintain a reference to MainActivity directly instead of Context, for example:
   `MainActivity context`;  instead of `Context context;`
   However, that means I cannot access my Preference from service.
2. Or may be I maintain reference to both service and MainActivity as following

   ```
    public Preferences(MainActivity context1, Service context2)
    {

       if(context1!=null)
           this.context=context1;
       else
           this.context=context2

       this.sharedPreferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
       sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }
   ```

Even in this case, I would instantiate Preferences from services as 
`new Preferences(null, this);`

I cannot call `StartActivityForResult` which is my ultimate objective.

What would be the cleanest solution in this case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [StartActivityForResult from a Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448485/startactivityforresult-from-a-service)

Comment: @MadhurAhuja: did you find the solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest solution would be to send an interface, something like `LocalPreferenceChangeCallback` defined in your class:

```
public static interface LocalPreferenceChangeCallback {
    void onPreferenceChanges();
}
```

Both service class and activity will implement this interface - feel free to add whatever parameters you wish for this method; the most important topic is to have the interface:

1. The activity will call `startActivityForResult`
2. The service will probably call `startActivity`

Send that interface as a parameter instead of `context`:

```
public final class Preferences implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private LocalPreferenceChangeCallback prefCallback;
    private final int FB_REQUESTCODE=1;
    private final int FB_SELCTFRIENDS=2;


    public Preferences(Context appContext, LocalPreferenceChangeCallback prefCallback)
    {
        this.prefCallback = prefCallback;
        this.sharedPreferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(appContext);
        sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }


    public String getFBFriends()
    {

        return sharedPreferences.getString(Keys.FB_FRIENDS.key, Defaults.FB_FRIENDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
            String key)
    {

        if (key.equals(Keys.FB_FRIENDS.key))
        {
            String fbFriendsVal = getFBFriends();
            if (fbFriendsVal.equals(Consts.FB_FRIENDS_FIRE))
            {
                if(prefCallback != null) {
                    prefCallback.onPreferenceChanges();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static interface LocalPreferenceChangeCallback {
        void onPreferenceChanges();
    }

}
```

You need to send some sort of `Context` anyway to instantiate `sharedPreferences` object, but you're only sending it because of this fact, you don't need to worry about how to handle preference change. In the end it's rather an OOP issue ...

Also the class naming is missleading as `Preferences` collides with [`java.utils.prefs.Preferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html).