# Using SAF from Service in Android

Tags: android, android-service, storage-access-framework

[SAF](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) operations seem to use `startActivityForResult` to trigger the UI picker. This makes sense since when the user selects a document on the picker, the calling activity receives the uri via `onActivityResult()`.

The problem is that I need to use SAF from a `Service` and [`startActivityForResult`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3448485/3715151) is `Activity`-specific. Is there another way to interact with SAF, one that can be used from an android service?

Comment: A service should only be working with a `Uri` that the user chose through the SAF activities. What is your use case for a service to try to work with storage providers in the absence of this?

Comment: @CommonsWare: I have an android service talking with external hardware connected to the phone. The user can take an action on this external device, e.g. let's say pressing a button, to transfer a file from the device to the phone or vice versa. When the user presses the button I want the SAF picker to show up, then the user can select a document to transfer it to the external device.

Comment: Then have your service start an activity that in turn uses the SAF normally.

Comment: "Then have your service start an activity that in turn uses the SAF normally." -- At the moment that's my plan, but feels like an hack.