# Android - startActivityForResult outside an Activity?

Tags: android, service, android-activity, bluetooth

I have a wrapper class (BluetoothDiscoverer) which is instantiated within a Service. This class obtains a BluetoothAdapter and checks whether Bluetooth is enabled before scanning for neighbouring devices.

Now if Bluetooth is not enabled I want to be able to do the following within this class (BluetoothDiscoverer):

```
Intent enableBluetoothIntent  = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);

startActivityForResult(enableBluetoothIntent, BLUETOOTH_ENABLER);
```

Now I have read this: [use startActivityForResult from non-activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848775/use-startactivityforresult-from-non-activity)

but I don't want to pass my Main Activity into this object since I want to deal with the result (whether the user accepts to enable bluetooth or not) 
within the BluetoothDiscoverer class.

Now If I make BluetoothDiscoverer a subclass of Activity

I seem to be getting a NullPointerException when the startActivityForResult is about to be called.

I think this is because I need to add an onCreate()/onDestroy() method, 
but this defeats the purpose of what I am doing as I need to be able to call methods on the BluetoothDiscoverer object within the service that instantiates this class.

I also need to register a broadcast receiver for retrieving neighbouring devices when a scan is initiated. If the BluetoothDiscoverer class is not an Activity, how do I register this receiver?

Is there a work around for this?

Thank you
Andreas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`startActivityForResult()` is only available from real on-screen activities. Please redesign your application so that the user interface is driven from activities, *then* have your service scan for devices.

> I also need to register a broadcast receiver for retrieving neighbouring devices when a scan is initiated. If the BluetoothDiscoverer class is not an Activity, how do I register this receiver?

You get rid of `BluetoothDiscoverer` and move its logic into the `Service`, which is a `Context` and therefore can register receivers.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Service`, create an `Activity` whose purpose is to request Bluetooth discoverability. Pass a `Messenger` along with the `Intent` for this `Activity` and have the `Activity` start the discoverability activity:

```
Intent enableBluetoothIntent  = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
startActivityForResult(enableBluetoothIntent, BLUETOOTH_ENABLER);
```

Then, inside `onActivityResult()` send a message via the `Messenger` back to your service.