# The method startActivityForResult(Intent, int) is undefined for the type ABC

Tags: android, android-layout, android-image, android-alarms, android-layout-weight

i have a class ABC with implements `Serializable` 
`ABC` class is an alarm class so using bunch of functions, i just wanted to upload image from SD card, to that i need to view images in `GRIDVIEW` then user need to select the IMAGE, this is the process
i have a method called `getImage()` to get the images from sd card..

```
  public void getImage() {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),1);

}
```

Getting an error `The method startActivityForResult(Intent, int) is undefined for the type ABC`
how can i rectify this ?

Comment: To start and activity from non-activity and non-fragment class, context will be required and that you can get from activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accept the `context` inside the non-activity class and cast it into `Activity`

```
 private Context context;
 private Activity activity;

public Example(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.activity = (Activity) context;
}
```

Then call it where ever you want

```
activity.startActivityForResult()
```

And if you want to get result later there itself, define a user defined `onActivityResult()` inside the non activity class

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
                             Intent intent) {}
```

And pass the result from the activity class to the user defined `onActivityResult()` method

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
                                Intent intent) {
    example.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short version: `startActivityForResult()` is only available from inside an activity or a fragment.

If you post more details about what you are trying to achieve I may be able to give you a more helpful answer

Comment: how to call from NON-Activity class pls?, is there any other way ?

Comment: You just can't do it mate, that's how the system works. However, I don't see any case where you would need to do it. If you think that it's your only solution, maybe you're looking at the problem from the wrong perspective. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @k3v1n4ud3 How did you saying it is not possible. refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848775/use-startactivityforresult-from-non-activity