# How to call startActivityforresult for non-activity

Tags: android

Is it possible to call **startActivityForResult()** from non Activity class to get the results?

Comment: There are lots of answer for this _topic_

Comment: **YES.** Please refer https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Comment: You'll need a reference to an `Activity` at least. Practically it probably makes sense to call it from an `Activity` though so you can also use the `onActivityResult` callback.

Comment: pass the activity as a parameter to that class, and using that call onActivityResult.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [use startActivityForResult from non-activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848775/use-startactivityforresult-from-non-activity)

Answer (score 1):

**Yes it is poosible**

You need an Activity on order to receive the result.

If its just for organisation of code then call other class from Activty class.

```
 public class Result {
 public static void activityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
      ...
 }
 }

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   Result.activityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call startActivityForResult from non-activity classes provided by calling activity  context and you can get the result in the same activity  within onActivityResult override method.